# R: dplyr using pipes to select data, and conduct t-tests with data from outside piped object

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a situation where I have data distributed between two dataframe, and I need to subset the data from one of the dataframes first, and then conduct a t-test between this subset data and the (entire) data from the other dataframe.

I attempted to use `%>%` and `group_by()` to select the data I want, and then I tried to invoke the t-test as shown below.

```
library(dplyr)
a <- c("AA","AA","AA","AB","AB","AB")
b <- c(1,2,3,1,2,3)
c <- c(12,34,56,78,90,12)
cols1 <- c("SampID", "Reps", "Vals")
df1 <- data.frame(a,b,c)
colnames(df1) <- cols1
df1

  SampID Reps Vals
1     AA    1   12
2     AA    2   34
3     AA    3   56
4     AB    1   78
5     AB    2   90
6     AB    3   12

e <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
f <- c(11,22,33,44,55,66,77,88,99)
cols2 <- c("CtrlReps","CtrlVals")
df2 <- data.frame(e,f)
colnames(df2) <- cols2
df2

  CtrlReps CtrlVals
1        1       11
2        2       22
3        3       33
4        4       44
5        5       55
6        6       66
7        7       77
8        8       88
9        9       99

df1 %>%
  group_by(SampID) %>%
  t.test(Vals, df2$CtrlVals, var.equal = FALSE)
```

This, however, returns an error:

```
Error in match.arg(alternative) : 
  'arg' must be NULL or a character vector
```

I also tried using `do` but that returns an error as well:

```
outputs <- df1 %>%
  group_by(SampID) %>%
  do(tpvals = t.test(Vals, df2$CtrlVals, data = ., paired = FALSE, var.equal = FALSE)) %>%
  summarise(SampID, pvals = tpvals$p.value)

Error in t.test(Vals, df2$CtrlVals, data = ., paired = FALSE, var.equal = FALSE) : 
  object 'Vals' not found
```

I am new to R, and I have exhausted my Google-Fu, so I have no idea what is happening. To the best of my knowledge, these two errors are unrelated, I think but resolving one or the other gives me a way out of the situation. I just don't know how. I am also sure that resolving this problem would immediately land me in the next problem (the one this post actually addresses).

Your inputs/guidance/help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempt with `do` was close, it can be fixed by doing:

```
outputs <- df1 %>%
    group_by(SampID) %>%
    do(tpvals = t.test(.$Vals, df2$CtrlVals, 
                       paired = FALSE, var.equal = FALSE)) %>%
    summarise(SampID, pvals = tpvals$p.value)
```

You need `.$Vals` to get at the `Vals` column within `do`, it doesn't work quite the same way as `mutate`. The `data` argument for `t.test` also isn't useful here as you don't have both variables in the same dataframe so you can't put them both in a formula.

Result:

```
> outputs
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  SampID pvals
  <fct>  <dbl>
1 AA     0.253
2 AB     0.862
```

Comment: Hi @Marius, thank you so much for your help! I tried this as you suggested, and it worked flawlessly.

In the interest of learning, may I ask why this code snippet works, even though the variable in it is not called with the `$`?

`df <- data.frame(x=abs(rnorm(50)),id1=rep(1:5,10), id2=rep(1:2,25))
df <- tbl_df(df)
res <- df %>% group_by(id1) %>% 
       do(w = wilcox.test(x~id2, data=., paired=FALSE)) %>% 
       summarise(id1, Wilcox = w$p.value)`

Edit: struggling with the editing, but I hope it is readable. Took this from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34581586/9494044).

Comment: That snippet works because you pass `data = .`, so the `wilcox.test` function can then look up the variables in the formula within the appropriate dataframe.

Comment: So the do snippet from my code would also work if it had been set up the same way (minus the variable being called from the other dataframe)?

Comment: Yes, if you call `t.test()` with `data = .`, you should be able to just put your variable names in a formula like `Vals ~ Group`, without having to do `.$Vals`.

Comment: I modified that code snippet with a `t.test` but it returns an `object not found` error.
`df <- data.frame(x=abs(rnorm(10)),y=abs(rnorm(50)),id1=rep(1:5,10),id2=rep(1:2,25))
df <- tbl_df(df)
res <- df %>% group_by(id1) %>%
  do(w = t.test(x, y, data=., paired=FALSE)) %>% 
  summarise(id1, Wilcox = w$p.value)`

Comment: I think the data argument only works when you are using a formula, like `t.test(x ~ group, ...)`. It doesn't work when you pass separate `x` and `y` vectors.